# How to make a variable accessible by other classes without subclassing?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I am using a switch to control if you can/cannot type in a text field. To do this, I am using a delegate in another swift file. I need to access the state of the switch, but I cannot use the delegate as a subclass of the class that the switch is in.

Comment: So basically you have a switch on screen A, and you do something on screen B that needs to access this switch?

Comment: This is all a bit vague but, can you tell the delegate the state of the switch when you call it from the thing that knows about the switch?

Comment: So the state is stored in the viewcontroller, and I think it has to be, but I need to access that state in another class, for example my delegate that uses it to determine weather the user can type or not. Maybe I could make the function need another parameter and enter it there?

Comment: The viewcontroller that has the reference on that switch should logically be the delegate of a model class that owns the state. Why is this not the case for you?

Comment: Just as I saw your comment, I figured it out. I used a function/delegate in the viewcontroller class (where the switch state is stored) and then used it directly in the function. Thank you :)

Comment: I think the idea that the state should live in the view controller is at fault. Shared state goes into the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a global structure to store properties like this:

**Const.swift**

```
struct Const {
  static var switchIsOn = false
  ...
}
```

Then you can access to this global property anywhere in you whole project like:
`Const.switchIsOn = true`

or

```
if Const.switchIsOn {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I was wondering how to use a global variable in swift. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by making the delegate a function in my ViewController class, where the switch state is stored. This allowed me to reference the switch state when needed without subclassing.